# Get-WmiCounter Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory Incomplete in non admin context

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, wmi

So I have created a script to gather counters using `Get-CimInstance` (which supercedes `Get-WMIObject`) and run it as a services via `srvany.exe`.

I get an issue where for the .Net CLR classes, some processes are missing not gathered, especially one that I want to monitor: `w3wp`. 
When running the application in an elevated Powershell console, the command returns all processes relying on .Net, whereas if I run it in a standard powershell console, only the local .Net processes are gathered.

I need to set up the appropriate permissions to that service so that it gathers all the metrics of all processes. I have tried running the process as Administrator, a domain admin account, to no avail. 
I've tried giving explicitly all the permissions on `root\cimv2` to the Administrator in the `wmimgmt.msc` WMI Admin console without solving the problem.

The default running context for services is SYSTEM, which is also the default running context for IIS.

I'm at a loss as to what permissions I need to give and where to allow this service to gather all the data. I feel that starting it as a service logging in as the admin account should be enough but apparently not.

Example of the issue in

```
PS C:\Users\user> gcim Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRSecurity | select-object Name

Name
----
_Global_
powershell
SCNotification
```

And now in a Run As Administrator powershell console:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> gcim Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRSecurity | select-object Name

Name
----
_Global_
powershell
w3wp
w3wp#1
w3wp#2
powershell#1
SCNotification
SCNotification#1
```

Using the alternative `Get-Counter` in an non-admin console is even worse:

```
PS C:\Users\user> Get-Counter -Counter "\.NET CLR Memory(*)\*" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 1
Get-Counter : The specified object was not found on the computer.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Counter "\.NET CLR Memory(*)\*" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand
```

Whereas it gives the right information ran in an admin console.